# Javascript function is being called on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

My javascript `switchDiv` function is being called on page load, when I don't want it to.  When its called, it goes through the switch statement and does each of the cases, except the default.  Anybody know how to fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#be-button").on("click", switchDiv(1));
$("#red-button").on("click", switchDiv(2));
$("#green-button").on("click", switchDiv(3));
$("#blue-button").on("click", switchDiv(4));
});

var switchDiv = function (mapNum) {
    console.log(mapNum);
    switch(mapNum) {
    case 1:
        $("#be-data").show();
        $("#red-data").hide();
        $("#green-data").hide();
        $("#blue-data").hide();
        break;
    case 2:
        $("#be-data").hide();
        $("#red-data").show();
        $("#green-data").hide();
        $("blue-data").hide();
        break;
    case 3:
        $("#be-data").hide();
        $("#red-data").hide();
        $("#green-data").show();
        $("blue-data").hide();
        break;
    case 4:
        $("#be-data").hide();
        $("#red-data").hide();
        $("#green-data").hide();
        $("blue-data").show();
        break;
    default:
        $("#be-data").show();
        $("#red-data").hide();
        $("#green-data").hide();
        $("#blue-data").hide();
}
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are executing the functions, rather than passing them as parameters.  Ie, you need to distinguish between passing a function:

```
function myFunc() { }
$("selector").on("click", myFunc);    // "myFunc" is the handler
```

And executing a function:

```
function myFunc() { }
$("selector").on("click", myFunc());  // execute "myFunc" -- its return value is the handler
```

Of course, you can't use the first in this case, since `switchDiv` itself has a parameter.  One way to get around this is to wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
$("#be-button").on("click", function() { switchDiv(1); });
```

Since you're doing this multiple times, however, you will probably want a helper function like "createHandler" or something:

```
function createHandler(num) {
    return function() { switchDiv(num); };
}

$("#be-button").on("click", createHandler(1));
$("#red-button").on("click", createHandler(2));
// etc
```

Comment: that did it!  ill choose your answer when i can :D