# jQuery addClass works only function in process. After hasClass doesn't work

Tags: jquery, class

In my function, I adding a class to current object. But when run again, the hasClass function doesn't detect the class I added.

So I can show a example that;

```
   var object = {
       func : function() {
           if ( $(this).hasClass('myclass') )
               // ...
           else
               $(this).addClass('myclass');
       }
   }

   $('#myobj').on('click', object.func);
```

Now,
I getting JSON data with AJAX. After I parsing JSON data and creating a DOM elements with this. When I click this dom elements, this function triggering successfully. Even addClass function works successfully. But when the function is triggered again, the hasClass function does not read the newly added class.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows the problem (because this should work: https://jsfiddle.net/kq6pwzvo/)

Comment: What element is `$(this)`? When and where `myFunction()` is being called? With just what you provided is impossible to see what might be wrong.

Comment: I updated. I hopefully you can understand.

Comment: Your function is being executed even before you click on the element. This might solve your problem: `$('#myobj').on('click', object.func);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503943/javascript-function-is-being-called-on-page-load

Comment: I'm sorry, already using same. Just I made a mistake when type here.

Comment: We will need to see more of your code then. Can't you put together a Codepen or JSFiddle to show us?

Comment: Duplicate of: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) -> ["Common problem: Using object methods as callbacks/event handlers"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/402037)

Comment: I solved this problem! It appeared because DOM elements were included in the page later.